# lifetime of combobox data bound to a dictionary

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I am still new in .net. Transferring an application from vba to SQL server + vb.net.
I have some comboboxes that are populated at form loading with data per language and circumstance. The data for the combobox are retrieved in a language class (part of a library dll) as a dictionary(of Integer, String)
I intend to populate the combobox from within a procedure in the language class as (MyComboBox inherits from forms.combobox with some custom properties):

```
Dim cbo As MyComboBox = CType(Ctrl, MyComboBox)
cbo.DataSource = New BindingSource(ComboboxData, Nothing)
cbo.ValueMember = "Key"
cbo.DisplayMember = "Value"
```

I am afraid however it won't work.
This code is part of a procedure called upon loading each form and once executed goes out of scope.
What about the bound data in the comboboxes. Are they transferred by value or are they linked By reference to ComboboxData and be lost once the called procedure returns control. If so is there another way to populate a combobox dynamically with a pair of value and display members from within a external class.

Comment: You wrote "I am afraid however it won't work." - did you try it and find a problem or are you concerned that it *might* not work?

Comment: That CBO is clearly being passed to something since it is being cast.  Why is that, where is that and can we see it

Comment: to Andrew, In a previous test I had following code:

Comment: @Andrew Sorry I'd like to answer to you but did not find out yet how to answer a structured text with code

Comment: @Plutonix, Ctrl is a control variable from "for Each Ctrl as Control in frm.Controls" to work with it I cast it to the right control type using "if typeof ctrl is ...." then casting

Comment: @Andrew, Yes I did make some previous tests with filling combo boxes from SQL datasets and had to assign a copy of the dataset returned from my SQL processing class to a different DataTable variable for each combobox but the situation was different as they were assigned sequentially in the same iteration. Thanks for your suggestion I'll first test before asking people for advise ... but you always learn chatting with other more experienced people.

Comment: @Plutonix, yr so right .... I have to refer to the control instead of assigning it. The way I wrote it it won't update the controls properties, thanks for your remark.

Comment: thanks for all of your answers. It works using with directcast(ctrl, MyComboBox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.I don't think you need to worry about - this is managed code and GS will clean everything up once nothing references it.

2.always set `ValueMember` and `DisplayMemeber` first, or your combobox makes double work. First it is trying to figure how to deal with your binding source, then it has to reconfigure.

3.You can use simple `List<T>`

```
Public class CboItem
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Description As String
End Class

Dim listOfItems As New List(Of CboItem)()
' load your list
cbo.ValueMember = "Id"
cbo.DisplayMember = "Name"
cbo.DataSource = listOfItems

cbo.SelectedIndex = 2 ' get third item
MessageBox.Show(DirectCast(cbo.SelectedItem, CboItem).Description)
```

4.you want to use `Using-End Using` construct when opening forms to make sure they go away and all resources released properly

5.*"...bound data in combo boxes..."* - it is not transferred. It is just that - bound. You have list somewhere, and you can use it as `dim a = cbo.DataSource`. And if you don't dispose your form, it may live in memory for awhile. Hence, pay attention to #4